# taking user input during execution-ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new in Ansible. I googled and read documentation for Ansible. But I am not able to find solution for my problem.

My issue -

In my Ansible playbook, I am running a command and as a result of that command the system asks me to input the password. I am not sure how can I put in the password in that promt.
I can save the password as var but not sure how to input it in that promt.

Any link to the documentation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the question with a snippet of your Ansible playbook, showing the `command` task at the very least?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing about with `expect`, you can usually just use the `stdin` argument to the `command` or `shell` module:

```yaml
- name: Do a thing
  command:
    cmd: myapp --flags --and --things
    stdin: "{{ the_password }}"

- name: Do a thing
  shell:
    cmd: myapp --flags --and --things
    stdin: "{{ the_password }}"
```

That should work for a lot of applications, but some will read from a controlling tty in preference to stdin (if they have a tty). For these, you can run them under `setsid` which prevents them from having a controlling tty, so they read from stdin instead:

```yaml
- name: Do a thing
  command:
    cmd: setsid myapp --flags --and --things
    stdin: "{{ the_password }}"
```

(This is assuming you're running under Linux, I don't know the appropriate thing to use for Windows/Mac)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the expect modulue. Here, I have an example

```yaml
- name: Executing RCU
  expect:
    command: >
      "{{ oracle_common }}/bin/rcu -silent -createRepository -connectString {{ connection_string }} 
       -dbUser {{ db_user  }} -dbRole {{ db_role }} -schemaPrefix {{ schema_prefix }} 
       -useSamePasswordForAllSchemaUsers {{ same_password|lower }} {{ list_components }}"
    responses:
      'Enter the database password': "{{ db_password }}"
      'Enter the schema password': "{{ schema_password }}"
    timeout: 1200 # Expect timeout by default is 30s. Here, I am using 20 minutes as RCU is slow
  no_log: yes
  register: rcu_output
  # RCU-6016 means the schemas with given prefix are in the database
  failed_when: "'ERROR - RCU' in rcu_output.stdout and 'CAUSE - RCU-6016' not in rcu_output.stdout"
  changed_when: false
```

In the previous example the command executed is asking for the database password, which is passed by using expect. What is more, it uses no_log: yes to avoid printing the password.

The documentation about expect module is available [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html)

The example I used is available [here](https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa/blob/master/roles/rcu/tasks/creatercuschemas.yml)

You should have pexpect on your machine to use expect.